# How to keep track of registry changes in a Windows based system

Tags: windows, .net, configuration

I want to track changes made to the registry through programming using preferably .Net Platform. I want to develop a solution in which I specifically need to track changes that happened to the registry, particularly the malicious ones, not the regular system install etc. I have found that the WMI can be helpful, more details are below: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2494270 can help track changes to registry. Is it a good idea or should I be looking into some other Windows APIs that target the need of detecting malicious activity in registry.

Comment: How is this question a product recomendation. this is ridiculous!

Comment: Well, sure, now that you edited it and removed that part.

Comment: Though to be honest, its not really so ontopic as it stands now, with the exception of the last part of the last sentence... Specifically "what API to use" would be an SO question, and "what parts of the registry to monitor" would be an SU question. Would you like to modify your q to focus on the security parts ("how to detect malicious activity"), or should I migrate it?

Comment: Agreed on clarification. You can hook the registry and get all the calls, but the security side is a different question, leading down the path to what level of inspection you're actually going to need.

Comment: @AviD Vote for SO as the SU questions could necessarily follow answers to the SO one(s). Hopefully easier for OP to edit in that direction, too.

Comment: This question is pertaining to the problem of information security. For now I want observe, monitor the changes made to the system by malware as follows:
prevent file from execution.
Enable automatic execution at system startup
Bypass Firewall
Enable Automatic execution at System startup

I hope this further clarifies enough or should I be posting registry changes as well?

Comment: @windowslabourer yes, you have security applications, but the primary question is an API/Windows OS internal operation question.